# Send audio using bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I have an Acer Liquid Metal with Froyo and an Alpine Car Stereo (bti 114).
I can use the stereo as headset perfectly and I've noticed that I can also hear the phone notifications when using it.
Can I stream phone mp3s to my car audio?
Any detailed information is very welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stereo supports bluetooth hands-free but not bluetooth audio, which is used to stream music, so no, this is not possible. For more information see [Bluetooth profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) on Wikipedia and compare Hands-free Profile (which the stereo supports) and A2DP (which it doesn't).

Theoretically, you *could* stream music through the HFP but the quality would be terrible, like listening to music in a phone call.

Comment: This is what I call pain